# How large can you set track_activity_query_size without incurring performance issues?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

We have some pretty large queries in our production postgresql (13.8) database that exceed the default 1024 for `track_activity_query_size` (some queries are over 100k).  I've bumped this value up to 8192, but it still does not capture quite a few of our queries.

I'm wondering:

1. How high can I reasonably set this (I've read 1MB is the max) without incurring performance issues?
2. What metrics can I monitor to track if I've set it too high?

I'd like to set it to 256k, or possibly higher, but that seems like it could be excessive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to give an authoritative answer to performance question; only a benchmark can do that. My answer is based on my understanding of the code.

The only impact that increasing `track_activity_query_size` has is that more memory is allocated in the process array at server start. The size of the process array is `max_connections` + `autovacuum_max_workers` + 1 + `max_worker_processes` + `max_wal_senders` + `max_prepared_xacts`, so you have to multiply `track_activity_query_size` by that number to see how much memory will be allocated.

The only performance impact is that you have less memory available for caching data and processing queries.

Comment: Thank you!  This is helpful.